# How do you reset screen zoom to zero?

Tags: keyboard, zoom

How do you reset screen zoom to zero?
I mean the one you do with control-mouse wheel, I know you can reset it with the wheel again until it gets to 1:1 but it would be nice to have a keyboard shortcut to make it 1:1
Is there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd say hold <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>–</kbd>. In fact, holding <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> will disable it, but once you press it again, it comes back to the old level, therefore <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>–</kbd> seems the best solution.

Comment: First you have to go into "Accessibility" (type into Spotlight), then click "Zoom", and enable the "Use keyboard shortcuts to zoom" checkbox.

Answer (score 5):

When zoom is enabled in accessibility preferences, <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>option</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> is the default shortcut for zooming out, it's not instant, but it's a pretty fast method.